# Create list of items repeated N times without repeating itself

Tags: python, numpy, adjacency-matrix

I would like to repeat a list N times but without repeating an item itself. For example,

```
from itertools import *

items = [ _ for _ in range(3)]
# repeat each item twice
row = sorted(list(chain(*repeat(items, 2))))
row

[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

BUT, I would like to create another list (col), which also has 6 items:

```
col = [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]
```

The goal of these lists is to create an adjacency matrix with diagonal items = 0. (COO format is my final goal so random.shuffle does not meet my need)

```
row = [0,0,1,1,2,2]
col = [1,2,0,2,0,1]
value = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

import scipy
mtx = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((value, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
mtx.todense()

matrix([[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0]])
```

I need the information into a COO format. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, the result should be in some random order? if not, just drop `sorted`

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the connection between `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]` and `[1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]` ?

Comment: maybe you should use `random.shuffle(all_items)` and later use some method to check if they do not repeat next to each other.

Comment: BWT: `items * 2` gives you `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]` so they do not repeat next to each other. And it doesn't need `repeat` nor `chain`

Comment: When you say "*without repeating an item itself*", did you mean "not necessarily" or "not at all"?

Comment: Hi I just added clarification to my original post. The ultimate goal is create a specific adjacency matrix. So I can't use shuffle.

Comment: Please provide an example where the output is not `np.one() - np.eye()`.

Comment: Still unclear. What does "_without repeating an item itself_" even mean?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, I don't want to create 'self-loop' and without repeating item itself in the col list make sure the diagonal = 0. Please refer to COO format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fill *all* the non-diagonal indices of a matrix of size `(n, m)`, you could do:

```py
n, m = 3, 3
value = [1,3,7,2,1,4]

row, col = np.where(np.arange(m)[:,None] != np.arange(n))
a = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=int)
a[row, col] = value

>>> a
array([[0, 1, 3],
       [7, 0, 2],
       [1, 4, 0]])
```

If you just want to make a dense array from a COO spec (with specified row, col indices and corresponding values):

```py
n, m = 3, 3
# or, if you only have row, col: n, m = np.max(np.c_[row, col], 0) + 1

row = [0,1,2,2]
col = [1,2,0,1]
value = [1,2,3,4]

a = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=int)
a[row, col] = value

>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! this exactly what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create a matrix of 1s with a diagonal of 0s, use [`numpy.identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html):

```
N = 3

out = 1 - np.identity(N, dtype=int)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

If you just want to create the `row`/`col` indices:

```
a = np.arange(N)
row, col = np.where(a[:,None]!=a)
```

Output:

```
# row
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])

# col
array([1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1])
```

Comment: You yourself just asked OP for clarification. Don't answer unclear questions with guesswork.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні well, I had a doubt after I answered, thus my question.

Comment: Thanks, I just added clarification to my original post.

Comment: Thank you @mozway but I would need a COO format.

Comment: @DaCard `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(out)`?

Comment: @moway, I have tried this but I need to create COO in advance before that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DaCard what exactly are your trying to achieve? A NxN matrix with only N items 0 is not really sparse. do you want to create `row` and `col`?

Comment: Goal is to create 2 lists: row & col --> then I will be able to use this (COO) formation to create an adjacency matrix for graph neural networks.

Comment: @DaCard then check the second part of my answer, but honestly, this is as expensive as creating a dense matrix directly ;)